# Need help submitting this particular form via javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, button, submit, form-submit

Ok so ive spent quite a while trying to find a JS command that will submit this page:

https://ta.yrdsb.ca/yrdsb/

Heres a few of the commands I've tried so far that I really thought would work, but didnt (I obviously tried them all separately):

```
document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();

(function() {document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();});

document.querySelectorAll("button[type='submit']")[0].click();

function () {querySelectorAll("button[type='submit']")[0].click;}
```

If someone can get me a command that will successfully submit this page, that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And did you try them right before the closing `</body>` tag or in an onload handler ?

Comment: Do you have a control in the form with a name of "submit"? If so, change (or remove) the name.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry im a complete noob to JS. Im entering these commands through chromes javascript console. Am i missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formRef.submit` isn't a function that submits the form, it is a reference to the input with the name and/or id `submit`.

You've destroyed the submit function.

Either rename the form control, or get a submit function from another form.

```
document.createElement('form').submit.apply( document.getElementById('loginForm') );
```

Comment: Oh my god, you genius. That did the trick. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I tried but it said "You can accept this answer in 5 minutes". So in 5 minutes i shall accept it.

Comment: You should really heed the advice given and not name your submit button `submit`, as that would be the most proper way to fix this.

Comment: The page isnt mine. I didnt name it.